# How to open a file with reverted change number of different client in perforce.?

Tags: perforce

I have reverted a file change accidentally(lets change number is X).Now I am editing another file under a different client ,But I want to change this file with older change number(X).please suggest me a way to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferring a pending change number between Perforce clients requires that the change spec be updated to associate it with the new client, which in turn requires that the change have no open files.

1. In the original client, run `p4 change CLN`.  Remove all open files in the change.  Save the updated change description and quit your editor.
2. In the original client, run `p4 change CLN` again.  Change the client name associated with the change to the name of the new client.  Note that you must do this separately from step 1; you cannot remove open files and change the client name simultaneously.
3. In the new client, run `p4 edit -c CLN FILE` (or if you've already opened the file for edit, `p4 reopen -c CLN FILE`).